# How to write a function or macro to send a parameter to a system call in gVim for Windows?

Tags: windows, macros, vim

The useful command

```
:r!date
```

is not so useful in gVim for Windows (not Cygwin's gVim) because Windows has its own date function which does not do what I want.

So, something like

```
:r!c:\cygwin\bin\date
```

would be great. But that's a lot to type. And considering that I might want to call a few things this way, it would be nice to write a function, which I could pass an argument `foo` and it would run

```
:r!c:\cygwin\bin\foo
```

What's the best way to do this? It should be:

1. Permanent: stored in `.vimrc` or some startup file.
2. Executed with as few keystrokes as possible.

Any suggestions for good places to create mappings are appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, a simpler solution for day-to-day use (especially if you are
interested in only one of the many system-like commands) would be
creating a custom synonym-command:

```
:command! -nargs=1 -range=% RR <line1>,<line2>read! c:\cygwin\bin\<args>
```

This tells Vim to create a new command named `RR` that accepts a range
and one (mandatory) argument. The command just passes arguments to
`read!` prepending `c:\cygwin\bin\` to the argument.

You could even provide a file completion for the files in `c:\cygwin\bin\`
directory. All you need for that to work is to create completion-list
function like this:

```
function! RRComplete(A, L, P)
    return system('dir /b /l c:\cygwin\bin')
endfunction
```

and then specify the name of that function when creating the command:

```
:command! -nargs=1 -complete=custom,RRComplete -range=% RR <line1>,<line2>read! c:\cygwin\bin\<args>
```

Answer (score 1):

`:h strftime()` ?

Otherwise, a longtime ago I wrote [system() wrappers](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/source/browse/#svn/system-tools/trunk) in order to execute external programs from vim either on *nix, or on win32-gvim with cygwin's bash or $COMSPEC as &shell.

Comment: Specifically, something like `:exe "normal! o" . strftime("%c") . "\\e"` would be equivalent, unless you know a better way?